# i am getting the following exception while encrypting the file via RSA key instance’s publickey method

Tags: python, cryptography, public-key-encryption

```
This is my code for encrypting a file:
```

Iam getting this following error "cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MODE_EAX'"
If i remove the  "AES.MODE_EAX" from the line NO 10 then i am getting the following error on line NO 12 (ciphertext, tag = cipher_aes.encrypt_and_digest(data)
AttributeError: AESCipher instance has no attribute 'encrypt_and_digest')

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Cipher import AES, PKCS1_OAEP
with open('encrypted_data.bin', 'wb') as out_file:
 recipient_key = open('public.pem').read()
 recipient_key=RSA.importKey(recipient_key)
 session_key = get_random_bytes(16)
 cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(recipient_key)
 out_file.write(cipher_rsa.encrypt(session_key))
 cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX)
 data = b'blah blah blah Python blah blah'
 ciphertext, tag = cipher_aes.encrypt_and_digest(data)
 out_file.write(cipher_aes.nonce)
 out_file.write(tag)
 out_file.write(ciphertext)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see cipher mode EAX anywhere in [the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Cipher.AES-module.html). That would indicate to me that it is not supported by PyCrypto in the current stable release (2.6.1).

However browsing through [the source code](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/lib/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py) I see that `MODE_EAX` is present. Therefore you might try using [the latest experimental build](https://ftp.dlitz.net/pub/dlitz/crypto/pycrypto/pycrypto-2.7a1.tar.gz), 2.7.1, in which `MODE_EAX` is supported.

However based on your usage of `encrypt_and_digest` I would guess you're using code that is not based on pycrypto but instead PyCryptodome. I am not familiar with the library personally but it has the functionality you're trying to use. You can [download it here](http://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/stable/src/introduction.html).

Comment: Leave that parameter my dear bro do you have any solution an error coming from line NO 12

Comment: Please see the edit, I've added a link to the library you need to use the method that's currently throwing your error on line 12.

Comment: Here it is showing SORRY            /
         \                         /
          \    This page does  not exist yet.

Comment: Sorry the link was not formatted properly. Try again now.